# How can I use a variable as Application Pool name?

Tags: powershell

The following code gives me the default app pool, converted to string. When I pass this variable

$appPoolName = Get-IISAppPool | Select-Object Name | Where-Object  {$_.Name -like "*Default*" } | Out-String

(Get-IISAppPool   $appPoolName).processmodel.username

I get the following error

[image]

Comment: No need for `Out-String`, you need to expand the property using either `-ExpandProperty` (*instead of `-Property`*), or *dot notation*: `$appPoolName = Get-IISAppPool | ? Name -like '*Default*'; (Get-IISAppPool $appPoolName.Name).processmodel.username`. **Edit**: Better yet, looks like only one call is needed: `(Get-IISAppPool | ? Name -like '*Default*').processmodel.username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
$appPoolName = (Get-IISAppPool | Where-Object Name -Match 'Default').Name
(Get-IISAppPool $appPoolName).processmodel
# Results
<#
IdentityType           : ApplicationPoolIdentity
IdleTimeout            : 00:20:00
IdleTimeoutAction      : Terminate
LoadUserProfile        : True
MaxProcesses           : 1
PingingEnabled         : True
PingInterval           : 00:00:30
PingResponseTime       : 00:01:30
Password               : 
ShutdownTimeLimit      : 00:01:30
StartupTimeLimit       : 00:01:30
UserName               : 
...
#>
```